# How do you bind one object's getters to another object?

Tags: javascript

Let's say you have `let a = { b: { c: 1 } }` and `const getters = { get c() { return this.b.c } }` and you spread `getters` into `a` like `a = { ...a, ...getters }`. `getters.c` is bound to the wrong `this`. How do you bind the methods in `getters` to `a` without having to write `bind` for each method (assume `getters` will have more getter methods in the future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using spread syntax will *invoke* getters:

```js
const obj = {
  get prop() {
    console.log('getter invoked');
  }
};
const obj2 = { ...obj };
```

It won't actually copy the getters, so that's not what you should use. Iterate over the keys and getter functions of the getter-object with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`, then use `Object.defineProperty` to put the getter on the `a` object:

```js
let a = {
  b: {
    c: 1
  }
};
const getters = {
  get c() {
    return this.b.c
  }
};

Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(getters)).forEach(([key, { get }]) => {
  Object.defineProperty(a, key, { get });
});
console.log(a.c);
```

Comment: What part of your solution decouples the `this` value from the methods in `getters`?

Comment: When `a.c` is referenced, the calling context will be `a`, so `this` will be `a` inside the getter already - no tweaking needed, as you can see by the runnable snippet which logs `1`

Comment: Worded differently, what part of your code changes `this` in `getters.c`  so that it refers to `a` and not `getters`? Is it when you destruct `{ get }`? Or does the context change when using `Object.defineProperty`?

Comment: What `this` refers to in a function depends on its calling context. It's not set in stone, and can be easily changed. Here, like I said above, since the calling context of `a.c` is `a`, the `this` inside the function will be `a`. Any time you invoke a standard function via `obj.fn()` (or invoke a similar getter), you'll call the function with a calling context of `obj`.

Comment: Oh, I just realized `a = { ...a, ...getters }` doesn't even work in the original post's example. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined at Object.get c`. Have any idea why?

Comment: See the first part of my answer: *Using spread syntax will invoke getters: <snippet> It won't actually copy the getters, so that's not what you should use.*

Comment: Oh, duh, ok that makes sense